# Is there an option to describe a command and list its possible options in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is there an option to describe a command and list its possible options in bash/zsh? I tried looking for one and I could only find `-h` but it does not work for me and gives me the error `bad option: -h` on zsh and `-h: invalid option` in bash. Same for `-?`.

Comment: It’s up to each command to implement `-h` to print help if it wants to. Some commands do. Some commands have a man page. Some commands don’t have any (local) help. So the answer is _no_.

Comment: No shell can have a possible knowledge of what options an **external** command supports. The writers of bash can't anticipate, what commands you will have installed on your system.  Of course, `bash` itself is usually installed with a man-page, and in this, you can find an explanation of the options available for the **internal** commands in bash.

Comment: `bash` has a `help XXX` builtin for builtins.

Comment: Some programs provide completion helpers that tell bash what options are available, but most software doesn't. There's certainly nothing global.

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate command `man`. Most commands, certainly all the traditional commands, have a man page. Try `man man`.

The GNU coding standards state, that:

> The standard --help option should output brief documentation for how to invoke the program, on standard output, then exit successfully. Other options and arguments should be ignored once this is seen, and the program should not perform its normal function.

So, for GNU programs, `--help` should provide you with the requested output (should, not will).

And for the rest: it is just wild west. Some implement `-h` for help. And others just believe that Google is the source for documentation.